# How to draw a rectangle over an element on the image using JavaFX?

Tags: javafx

I have an image which is displayed on my JavaFX application. Given the coordinates, I must display that part on the image using a rectangle. For example, if there is a textfield on the image and I give the coordinates of the textfield, a rectangle should appear over the textfield on the image (Just like highlighting it).
Drawing a rectangle is easy, but I'm having difficulty positioning it on the image. Please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use a parent component that does not layouts its children automatically. For this you can use `Pane`:

```
@Override
public void start( final Stage primaryStage )
{
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView( ... );
    // Optional: locating the image at iX-iY
    // imageView.setX( iX );
    // imageView.setY( iY );

    Rectangle r = new Rectangle( rX, rY, width, height );

    // Add rectangle at the last, so it shows up on the top of other children
    Pane pane = new Pane( imageView, r );

    final Scene scene = new Scene( pane, 400, 300 );
    primaryStage.setScene( scene );
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: What would the benefit of this be over a `StackPane`?

Comment: @ChristopherSmith. StackPane will align center vertically and horizontally by default regardless its children x and y properties. However the Pane (super class of all panes) will not do that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `StackPane` for this.

```
StackPane stackPane = new StackPane();
ImageView imageView = ...;
stackPane.getChildren().add(imageView);
Rectangele rectangle = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
stackPane.getChildren().add(rectangle);
```